# Android Proguard with MultiDex (Unknown constant type [100] in constant pool) failed

Tags: android, proguard, android-gradle-plugin

Build Information:

```
compileSdkVersion = 19
buildToolsVersion = '21.1'
```

gradle configuration (omit trivial options):

```
android {
defaultConfig {
    multiDexEnabled true
}
signingConfigs {
    release {
        ...
    }
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        proguardFile 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}
dexOptions {
    preDexLibraries = false // this one doesn't matter
}
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.+'
}
}
```

I believe that other configurations(like MultiDexApplication) are fine, because debug build works well.

But when I execute assembleRelease (a.k.a with Proguard) it failed by error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:shrinkReleaseMultiDexComponents'.
java.io.IOException: Can't read [/(some locations)/build/intermediates/classes-proguard/release/classes.jar] (Can't process class [com/nhn/android/naverlogin/ui/OAuthLoginImage.class] (Unknown constant type [100] in constant pool))
```

Here is related Proguard options:

```
-keep public class com.nhn.android.naverlogin.** {*;}
-keep public class com.nhn.android.naverlogin.ui.** {*;}
-dontwarn com.nhn.android.navelogin.**
-libraryjars libs/naveroauthlib-4.0.1.jar
-keepclassmembers class * {
 public static <fields>;
 public *;
}
```

Anybody faced these kinds of `Unknown constant type [100] in constant pool` Error?

Comment: Is this issue resolved?? If yes then please provide a solution

Comment: This is is automatically solved after buildtools and related library update.